Bootstrap not working with Rails 8 Beta 1 (Propshaft::MissingAssetError)
Fresh install of Rails 8.0.0.beta1 and Ruby 3.5.5.  New Rails app runs no problem using rails new new_app, but using rails new new_app --css bootstrap the following error appears on every page load (after generating a controller and view, etc.):
Propshaft::MissingAssetError

Showing /new_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #23 raised: 
The asset 'application.css' was not found in the load path.

On this extracted source /new_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>

The stylesheet_link_tag is triggering the error.
The guides online make it seem like this should work out of the box.  Not sure why I am getting an error.  Ideas on how to fix?
Appreciate the help.  I'm a beginner.  Forgive me for the basic question.

are you running bin/dev?

did you solve it??

install node and yarn before rails new
application.bootstrap.scss needs build and watch it
